# If i disable wysiwyg, is it going to delete the content?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, wysiwyg

If I disable WYSIWYG, is it going to delete the content that is inside?

I'm not sure about it and do not want to take the chance.

I'm trying to add automatic meta description from the description but it takes the code from the WYSIWYG instead of the content inside.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you saved all the necessary data in the DB, you're good. If you are not sure, check the cms_page table. For blocks, check cms_blocks

Answer (score 0):

If the data has been saved into the database, disabling the WYSIWYG editor will not delete the content.

But I think if you have used formatting (like pressed ENTER key, used **BOLD**, *ITALIC* in the content), then your content may not be usable for generating automatic meta description due to HTML tags in it.